# Prove that $\ln x \leq x^{\alpha}$ for large x and that there exists a constant $c$ such that $\ln x \leq c x^{\alpha}$ $\forall x\in [1,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Question:** Assume $(\ln x)' = \frac1x$, $(x^\alpha)' = \alpha x^{\alpha-1}$ for all $x>0$, $\ln(e^x)=x$ and that $\alpha>0$.

1. Prove that $\ln x \leq x^\alpha$ for large x.
2. Prove that there exists a constant $c_\alpha$ such that:

   (a) $\ln x \leq c_\alpha x^\alpha$ for all $x \in [1,\infty)$

   (b) $c_\alpha \rightarrow \infty$ as $\alpha \rightarrow 0^+$

   (c) $c_\alpha \rightarrow 0$ as $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$

**Attempt:**

1. Consider $f(x) = \frac{\ln x}{x^\alpha}$. Then $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) \stackrel{\text{L'H}}{=} \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\alpha x^\alpha}=0.$$ This implies that $x^\alpha$ grows at a faster rate than $\ln x$. Therefore, $\ln x \leq x^\alpha$ for large x.
2. I'm thinking that if a function is greater than another, then the derivative of the larger function should be greater than (or equal to) the derivative of the smaller function as x gets large. Therefore, taking the derivatives and solving for x we get: $$\frac1x = \alpha x^{\alpha-1} \Rightarrow x = \left( \frac1\alpha \right)^{\frac1\alpha}.$$
   So I thought I should let $c_\alpha = \left( \frac1\alpha \right)^{\frac1\alpha} - 1$ so that it satisfies conditions b and c, but it does not satisfy condition a. I need a hint.

Comment: Your statement (2) is not correct.  For example if $f(x)=x+x^{-1}$ and $g(x)=x$ then $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x>0$, but $f'(x)<g'(x)$.  Draw graphs of $f$ and $g$ on the same axes and you will understand what is happening here.

Comment: @David: Thanks. I am looking at a graph of both functions. $f'(x) \rightarrow g'(x)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. This was the kind of idea I thought would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **PRIMER:**
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1 }\tag 1$$
>
> for $x>0$.
>
> Aside, I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033271/test-for-convergence/2033309#2033309), using elementary (pre-calculus) tools, that for all positive integers, $\log(n) \le \sqrt{n}$.  In fact, $\log(x)\le \sqrt{x}$ for all $x>0$.

---

Note that $\log(x)\le x-1<x$ for $x>0$.  Then, $\alpha \log(x)=\log(x^\alpha)\le x^\alpha$.  If $\alpha >0$, then we have

$$\log(x)\le \frac{x^\alpha}{\alpha}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Is it safe to say that for any real-valued function, say $f$, the following inequality holds: $$\log(f) \leq f-1$$

Comment: Yes, if $f>0$, then $\log(f)\le f-1<f$.

Comment: How should I go about proving the inequality holds for any positive real-valued function?

Comment: @SOULed_Outt I've added a primer with a link to an answer I posted [HERE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) using elementary tools only.  -Mark

Comment: @SOULed_Outt You're welcome.  I also showed in [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033271/test-for-convergence/2033309#2033309), using elementary (pre-calculus) tools, that for all positive integers, $\log(n) \le \sqrt{n}$.  And in fact, $\log(x)\le \sqrt{x}$ for all $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Use differentiation to show that
$$f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x^a}$$
has a maximum value of $\dfrac1{ae}$.