# Test for convergence:

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying a chapter of my Analysis book, it's on convergence and divergence tests for series. The chapter concludes with some series to test, and these are the few I am having problem with:

Test for convergence:
$$\sum \frac{\ln{k}}{k^2}$$
$$\sum (\sqrt[k]{k}-1)$$
$$\sum \frac{k!}{k^k}$$

Now for the first series. It's obvious to by writing out terms that $\ln{k}\le \sqrt{k}$ and that the comparison test therefore yields that the given series converges. However I am failing to prove the $\ln{k}\le \sqrt{k}$ without using derivatives and other calculus-related methods, and I'm interested in a rather neat way of proving the given series converges.

For the second one.. It's clear that $\sqrt[k]{k}$ goes to $1$ as $k$ get's really large, (I've proven that in an earlier chapter), but I'm not sure how to test this series.

The third series seems to converge when I write out the first terms. I notice that the terms are less or equal than those of $\sum \frac{1}{2^k}$, which I know converges. However here again I'm having trouble proving these inequalities (at least in a neat way).

Comment: For the first: what tools do you have available, and what is your definition of a logarithm? For the second: the "obvious" way is to use either the exponential series, or perhaps the mean value theorem. This is another case which is easy with techniques from calculus, but it's not sure what tools you have at your disposal. For the third: matching each term of the factorial with a corresponding term from $k^k$ and throwing away all but the first two (say) shows that your series is bounded above by $\sum 1\cdot 2/(k^2)$, which converges quickly enough.

Comment: Really not much calculus (if not none) is involved here. Basically this chapter's main theorems this far are: integral test, comparison test, limit comparison test, Cauchy's condensation test. I'm gonna look at your solution for the third one right now.

Comment: Oh that final one is indeed very clear. $\frac{1}{k}\frac{2}{k}\frac{3}{k}...\frac{k}{k} \le \frac{1}{k}\frac{2}{k}$ since every term  $\frac{3}{k}...\frac{k}{k}$ is smaller than or equal to $1$. Thanks for your answer. Any help on the other 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Herein, we show using non-calculus based tools that $\log(x)\le \sqrt{x}$ , and in particular that $\log(k)\le \sqrt{k}$ for all integer $k\ge 1$.  We begin with a primer on an elementary inequalities for the logarithm and exponential functions.

> **PRIMER:**
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm and exponential functions satisfy the inequalities
>
> $$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1\tag1$$
>
> for $x>0$, and
>
> $$1+x\le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x} \tag 2$$
>
> for $x<1$.

---

**PROBLEM $(1)$:**

Let $f(x)=\frac x2-\log(x)$.  Then, using $(1)$ we find for $h>0$ that

$$\begin{align}
f(x+h)-f(x)&=\frac h2-\log\left(1+\frac hx\right)\\\\
&\ge \frac h2-\frac hx\\\\
&\ge 0
\end{align}$$

for all $x\ge 2$.  So, $f(x)$ is monotone increasing for $x\ge 2$. And since $f(2)=1-\log(2)>0$ we have

$$\log(x)<x/2 \tag 3$$

for $x\ge 2$.

Now, setting $x= \sqrt{k}$ in $(3)$ reveals

$$\log(k)\le \sqrt k$$

for $k\ge 4$.

We also have from $(1)$, that $\log(x)\le 2(\sqrt x-1)$.  When $x\le 4$, we see that $2(\sqrt x-1)\le \sqrt x$.

Hence, for all $x>0$, we find that $\log(x)\le \sqrt x$.  Certainly then for all integer $k\ge 1$, $\log(k)\le \sqrt{k}$ as was to be shown!

---

**PROBLEM $(2)$:**

We can write $k^{1/k}=e^{\frac1k \log(k)}$.  Using the left-hand side inequality in $(2)$ reveals

$$k^{1/k}-1\ge \frac{\log(k)}{k}>\frac{1}{k}$$

for $k\ge 3$.  The series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k^{1/k}-1)$ diverges by comparison with the harmonic series.

---

PROBLEM $(3)$

Note that we can write

$$ \frac{k!}{k^k} =\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots k}{k\cdot k\cdot k\cdots k}\le \frac 2{k^2}$$

The series converges by comparison with the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$.

Comment: I don't understand either of your explanations (I'm sorry). How does your formula work with $x, h$ and $t$ in problem 1? I don't understand the first equality there. Also I don't understand how you got the inequalities in problem 2.

Comment: The $t$ was a typo.  It is $x$, and I've edited.  The inequalities in the second problem come from Equation $(2)$ in the primer.  $$k^k-1=e^{\frac1k \log(k)}-1\ge 1+\frac{\log(k)}{k}-1=\frac{\log(k)}{k}>\frac1k$$for $k\ge3$ since $\log(x)\ge 1$ for $x\ge e$.

Comment: All right, thanks for your clarifications. Perhaps if you want you could explain how you got to the first two inequalities, however maybe that's a different question?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I embedded a link to another answer I posted that provides the details.

Comment: I've added the "missing link."  And yes, the pun is intended. -Mark

Answer (score -1):

Why downvoting. it is correct .

**Hint**  for he first
$x\mapsto \ln(x)-\sqrt{x}$ is decreasing $\implies \ln(x)\leq \sqrt{x}$  for large enough $x$.

we have

$$\lim_{k\to+\infty}k^{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{\ln(k)}{k^2}=0$$

since the power grows quickly than logarithm.

$$\implies k^{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{\ln(k)}{k^2}\leq 1$$ for large enough $k$.

$$\implies \frac{\ln(k)}{k^2}\leq \frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

and you can conclude.

> for the second

$$\sqrt[k]{k}-1=e^{\frac{\ln(k)}{k}}-1\sim \frac{\ln(k)}{k}\;\;(k\to+\infty)$$

use the integral comparison test.

Comment: I would say that this answer is not helpful. The OP is aware that $\ln x < \sqrt x$, which is essentially the only ingredient in this answer. The OP is more concerned with how to show that $\ln x < \sqrt x$, which is hidden in your answer by "since the power grows quickly than logarithm."

Comment: Yes but that's a rather calculus-way of proving it.

Comment: Why this answer is downvoted.