# Proving the sequence $a_n=\frac{\ln(n+7)}{n}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

As the title says, I'm trying to prove that the sequence $$a_n=\dfrac{\ln(n+7)}{n}$$ converges. I'm trying to use the squeeze theorem and l'hopitals rule, but I'm not making any progress. I just ran a quick simulation and it seems that $a_n$ converges to $0$.

How do I go about proving this?

Comment: I think $a_n=\ln(n+7)/n$ and $x$ is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

First write:   $\ln(n+7) = \ln n + \ln\left(1+\frac{7}{n}\right)$,  and use the popular inequality:  $\ln(1+x) \le x$ with $x = \frac{7}{n}$ we have:

$0 < a_n \le \dfrac{\ln(n)}{n}+\dfrac{7}{n^2}=\ln\left(\sqrt[n]{n}\right)+\dfrac{7}{n^2}\to \ln(1) + 0 = 0$. You need to verifty that $\sqrt[n]{n} \to 1$ by using a sleek AM-GM inequality as this: $1\le \sqrt[n]{n} = \sqrt[n]{1\cdot 1\cdots\sqrt{n}\cdot \sqrt{n}}\le \dfrac{1+1+\cdots + 1+ \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}}{n}= \dfrac{n-2+2\sqrt{n}}{n}= 1-\dfrac{2}{n}+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$ which converges to $1$ by squeeze lemma, and the main statement follows. In doing this "proof", we avoided bothering the L'hospitale rule as much as we could.

Answer (score 1):

The squeezing theorem (assume $x>0$):

$0 \leq \frac{\ln{(x+7)}}{x} \leq \frac{x+7}{x}$

It's fairly easy to see that $\frac{x+7}{x}$ converges to one, so this doesn't work.

L'Hôpital's rule says:

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x+7)}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{  \frac{d}{dx} \ln{(x+7)}  }{ \frac{d}{dx} x  } = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x+7} = 0$

Comment: $\frac{x+7}{x}\to 1$ as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Well, L'Hôpital gives it then.

Comment: Please correct the first part of this post;  it is blatantly false!

Answer (score 0):

I showed in [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033271/test-for-convergence/2033309#2033309), that the logarithm function satisfies the inequality

$$\log(n)\le \sqrt{n} \tag 1$$

for $n\ge 1$.

Using $(1)$ reveals that

$$0\le \frac{\log(n+7)}{n}\le \frac{\sqrt{n+7}}{n}\tag 2$$

whereupon applying the squeeze theorem to $(2)$ yields the coveted limit

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log(n+7)}{n}=0}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark