# Determining if a series converges conditionally or absolutely

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine whether the following series converges conditionally, or converges absolutely. $$\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)}{\sqrt{k}\ln(k)}$$

What could I use here to work this out? This isn't monotone. I've tried using the Ratio Test but this seems kinda cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this?

Was I even allowed to use the Ratio Test? I've just remembered it's not for $\sum^\infty_{n=c}$ but for $n=1$.

Comment: Regarding your last question, in issues of whether things converge or not, where you start the series is always irrelevant. Convergence is about the infinite tail of the series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)}{\sqrt{k}\ln(k)}=\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}\ln(k)}$$

thus it converges conditionally by [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)  while

$$\sum^\infty_{k=2}\left|\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)}{\sqrt{k}\ln(k)}\right|=\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}\ln(k)}$$

diverges by [limit comparison test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/677042/505767) with $\frac{1}{k^\frac34}$.

For the latter, as an alternative suggested by [Mark Viola](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/218419/mark-viola), note that since for any $a>0$

$$\log x^a\le x^a-1 \implies\log x\le \frac{x^a-1}{a}<\frac{x^a}{a}$$

selecting $a=\frac12$ we have

$$\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}\ln(k)}>\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{1}{2k}$$

Comment: @ClementC. Oh yes of course, Thanks I fix

Comment: Note that for any $a>0$, we have $$\log(x)\le \frac{x^a-1}{a}<\frac{x^a}{a}$$So, taking any $0<a\le 1/2$ suffices here.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes Mark of course I've just take a value in this range (doesn't it should be 0<a< 1/2?).

Comment: Since the harmonic series diverges, we can  select $a=1/2$ here.

Comment: @MarkViola I'm referring to limit comparison test with "a" such that $$\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}\ln(k)}}{\frac1{k^a}}\to \infty$$ and with "a=1/2" I could not conclude.

Comment: Yes, but I'm suggesting you forgo that and use the comparison test, which I believe is more straightforward and easier to understand intuitively than the LCT.

Comment: @MarkViola Oh yes very nice Mark, I'm addicted with LCT but in this case that really more straightforward and clear.

Comment: (+1) for the edited result.  I corrected for the missing factor of $2$ in the denominator.  As it turns out, one can show with more work that $\log(k)\le \sqrt k$ for $k\ge 2$.

Comment: @MarkViola It's an upovote for you and thanks for the edit, I had considered 2/k but 1/(2k) is the correct bound!

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033271/test-for-convergence/2033309#2033309) is a simple, pre-calculus proof, that $\log(x)\le \sqrt x$.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks a lot Mark I will study you work on it!

Comment: I get to showing the limit of $a_k$ is zero (as required) and $\frac{1}{\infty}$ shows up. Would this just be zero?

Comment: @AustereTiger are you referring to the alternating series test or to the second one?

Comment: @gimusi The alternating series test.

Comment: @gimusi Using calculus it's easy to show that $\log(x)\le x^a$ for all $x>0$ whenever $a\ge 1/e$.

Comment: @AusterTiger $a_k \to 0$ is always necessary. To apply alternating series test to $\sum (-1)^k a_k$ we need  that $a_k$ is monolitically decreasing which is the case here since $\sqrt k \ln k$ is the product of two increasing functions thus the reciprocal is strictly decreasing.

Comment: @gimusi That's what I'm saying. $a_k$ must be approaching zero. To apply the alternating series test in the first place, surely I need to show that the limit is actually zero?

Comment: @AustereTiger Yes of course that’s a necessary condition for al kind of series to converge.

Comment: That's what my problem is then. As I said, $\frac{1}{\infty}$ shows up in the limit calculation. That's one of those unintuitive ones where you could probably just say it equals zero but I would rather show it. I was thinking of using the Squeeze Theorem to show the limit is zero.

Comment: @AustereTiger We don’t need squeeze theorem since it is not an indeterminate form you can refer to it as a given result by limit theorems http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitProofs.aspx

Comment: @gimusi Thank you for that :) I'll look at the proof.

Comment: @AustereTiger You are welcome, please do not hesitate to ask for any other clarification, I don't know your level of knowledge on this topic thus maybe I've assumed mny things as given but if something is not clear you can ask for it. Bye

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sin(\pi/2 +k\pi)$ just alternates between $1$ and $-1,$ so has absolute value $1$. So absolute convergence is just about $\frac{1}{\sqrt k \ln k}.$ For this I recommend a comparison with $1/k$. For the convergence of the series itself I recommend the alternating series test.

Comment: But for the alternating series test, doesn't the series have to be non-increasing?

Comment: Yes, and it is.

Comment: It is? How do we know?

Comment: The function $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is increasing, and so is $x\mapsto \ln x$. So $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}\ln x$ is increasing, and $x\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\ln x}$ is decreasing (on $(1,\infty)$).

Comment: The absolute value of the series must be non-increasing, that is. (If that was the confusion.) No alternating series is monotonic, so it’d be a pretty useless test if that were the criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we will study if the serie
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\right)}{\sqrt{k}\ln(k)}\right|$$
converges, because if it does, directly we have that our original one does too. 
Note that 
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\right)=(-1)^{k}$$
so we have that 
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\right)}{\sqrt{k}\ln(k)}\right|=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}\ln(k)}\right|=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}\ln(k)}$$

Now, we're going to use the integral test for convergence

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

As the integral 
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\ln(x)}dx=\int_{\ln(2)}^\infty  \frac{e^t}{t\sqrt{e^t}}dt =\int_{\ln(2)}^\infty  \frac{1}{t\sqrt{e^{-t}}}dt $$
has not a primitive on elementary function, we can proceed comparing this integral with another and apply the comparison test for improper integrals

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ImproperIntegralsCompTest.aspx

Comparing it  with $g(t)=\frac{1}{t}$, we get that
$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{t\sqrt{e^{-t}}}}{\frac{1}{t}}=\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-t}}}=+\infty$$
and as $g$ diverges, $f$ does it too.

Comment: $\frac{e^t}{\sqrt{e^t}}=e^{t/2}$ and $\int_1^L \frac{e^{t/2}}{t}\,dt\ge \int_1^L\frac1t\,dt$, which diverges logarithmically.  But we don't need the integral test here.  Note that $\log(k)\le \frac{k^a-1}{a}$ for all $a>0$.  So, just choose $a$ to equal anything less than or equal to $1/2$ and you're done since the harmonic series diverges.