# Prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\text{log}(x+1)}{x} = 0$ without de l'Hopital rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\text{log}(x+1)}{x} = 0$

I know that $\text{log}(x+1)$ goes to infinity more slowly than $x$, but I'm not able to prove the limit above without using de l'Hopital rule.

Ideally, the proof should be algebraic and not with a graphic showing that $\text{log}(x+1)$ goes to infinity more slowly than $x$.

Comment: Well, there's the usual go-to cheater answer of using a Taylor series expansion, but that's just L'Hospital's rule in disguise

Comment: as $\lim_{y \to \infty} e^y- 1 = \infty$ th calculus of limits tells us that the value you seek is equal to $\lim_{y \to \infty}\frac{\ln(e^y - 1 + 1)}{e^y - 1} = \lim_{y \to \infty}\frac{y}{e^y - 1}$. If you are able to use results about the exponential function you may have an easier time with this limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\log(x+1)}x}{\frac{\log(x)}x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(x)+\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}{\log(x)}=1,$$it is enough to prove that$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(x)}x=0.$$Doing $x=e^y$, this becomes$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac y{e^y}=0.$$But, if $y>0$,$$e^y=1+y+\frac{y^2}2+\cdots>\frac{y^2}2,$$and therefore$$0<\frac y{e^y}<\frac y{y^2/2}=\frac2y\to0.$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that for $x\gt 0$, $\log(1+x)=2\log \sqrt{x+1}\le 2\sqrt {x+1}$

On dividing the inequality by $x$, we get for large $x$

$0\le \frac{\log(1+x)}x\le2\sqrt{\frac 1x+\frac 1{x^2}}$

The result follows by squeeze principal.

**Note:** The inequality used in first line follows from the famous inequality for all $t\gt 0$, $\log t\le t$.

A short proof (using application of derivatives) for the inequality could go along these lines:

Let $g(x)=\log t-t$. It would suffice to show that $g(x)\le 0$ for all $x\gt 0$. Clearly for $0\lt t\le 1$ the inequality holds as $\log t$ is non positive on $(0,1]$.
So we can concentrate on $t\gt 1$ and noting that derivative of $g$ that is $g’(t)\lt 0$ for all $t\gt 1$, it follows that $g$ is decreasing on $[1,\infty)$ so $g(t)\lt g(1)=0$ for all $t\gt 1$ and hence the inequality follows.

Comment: How did you arrive at the first inequality?

Comment: @DatBoi See [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033271/test-for-convergence/2033309#2033309)

Comment: @Koro Nice answer, but writing things in terms of the square root is not necessary.

Comment: Although Mark Viola has supplied support for it in the comments, the fact that $\log(x)\le x$, used in the first inequality, should be supported in the answer.

Comment: @robjohn: professor Robjohn, I wrote that with the idea that the OP would be familiar with the inequality.

Comment: I sort of assumed that the question was for someone who did not know that inequality. If someone knew that $\log(x)\le x$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{2\log(x)}{x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac2x\underbrace{\frac{\log(x)}{x}}_{\in[0,1]}=0$. But who knows without more context.

Comment: @robjohn: Yes. So what are you suggesting? Should the answer be revised?

Comment: Well, since someone asked how you arrived at the first inequality, it would be nice to include, in the answer, something about that, or at least state that you are assuming that inequality. Comments are not always permanent, so content in them may be lost.

Comment: @robjohn: thanks for the suggestion. I added a short proof. I didn’t respond to Datboi question in comment asking about the inequality as Mark Viola had responded already to that and I thought that was enough to answer Datboi’s question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that only uses basic properties of $\log(n)$ and [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

For $n\ge3$,
$$
\begin{align}
(n+1)^{n+1}
&=n^{n+1}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}\tag{1a}\\
&\le4n^{n+1}\tag{1b}\\
(n+1)^n
&\le\frac4{n+1}n^{n+1}\tag{1c}\\
&\le n^{n+1}\tag{1d}\\
\frac{\log(n+1)}{n+1}
&\le\frac{\log(n)}n\tag{1e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: distributive property
$\text{(1b)}$: as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245), using only Bernoulli's Inequality,
$\phantom{\text{(1b):}}$ $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}$ is decreasing; thus, for $n\ge1$, we have $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}\le4$
$\text{(1c)}$: divide by $n+1$
$\text{(1d)}$: $n\ge3$
$\text{(1e)}$: take logs and divide by $n(n+1)$

$(1)$ shows that $\frac{\log(n)}{n}$ is decreasing for $n\ge3$. Since $\frac{\log(n)}{n}$ is bounded below by $0$, $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n}$ exists.

Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
L
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(2n)}{2n}\tag{2a}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(2)}{2n}+\frac12\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}n\tag{2b}\\
&=0+\frac12L\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: definition
$\text{(2b)}$: $\log(2n)=\log(2)+\log(n)$
$\text{(2c)}$: take the limits

$(2)$ says that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n}=L=0$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n+1)}n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n+1)}{n+1}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}\tag{3a}\\[6pt]
&=0\cdot1\tag{3b}\\[9pt]
&=0\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

One more method trying to use **only** elementary facts.

Suppose, for $a>1$, we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log_a n}{n}=0\quad(1)$$
and let's consider any $x_n\to +\infty$. As we have $\left\lfloor x_n \right\rfloor \leqslant x_n \leqslant \left\lfloor x_n \right\rfloor+1$, then, for appropriate $n$, holds

$$ 0\leqslant \frac{\log_a x_n}{x_n} \leqslant \frac{\log_a ( \left\lfloor x_n \right\rfloor+1)}{\left\lfloor x_n \right\rfloor}=\frac{\log_a ( \left\lfloor x_n \right\rfloor+1)}{\left\lfloor x_n \right\rfloor+1}\cdot\frac{ \left\lfloor x_n \right\rfloor+1}{\left\lfloor x_n \right\rfloor}$$
where in right hand we have subsequences of $(1)$ and $\frac{n+1}{n}\to 1$, so right side tends to zero.

Now for $(1)$  I assume we know $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{b^n}=0$, for $b>1$, based on binomial theorem. So, for appropriate $n$, we have $\frac{1}{b^n} < \frac{n}{b^n}<1$. Let's take $b=a^\varepsilon$, where $a>1$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Then we obtain $\frac{1}{a^{n\varepsilon}} < \frac{n}{a^{n\varepsilon}} < 1$, or, same is $1<n<a^{n\varepsilon}$. From last we obtain
$$0< \log_a n < n\varepsilon$$
and at last
$$0< \frac{\log_a n}{n} < \varepsilon$$
which gives $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Reversing the order of operations we have:

$\text{log}\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}(x+1)^\frac{1}{x}=$,

$log(1)=0$.

Comment: It is not $\text{lim}_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1 + x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = 1$ but $\text{lim}_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1 + 1/x)^{x} = e$.